# Images is not showing after migration wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have done migration of word-press from one server to another 
I have a link in which i am showing images, but the image exist in the directory, when i visit direct image it is showing 404.

Here is example link

**http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/9780007322602-100x128.jpg**

But i doubled checked image is sitting into upload folder

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Double then tripple check the URL again. Look for typos and casing. Check permissions on the files, and the parent folders. Double check the URL again. Can you access other static files like CSS/JS?

Answer (score 0):

Moving a site from one domain to another requires you to replace the domain name in  all the links in posts / pages. This can be done using a database search and replace.

You should use the migration plugin if you are not familiar with the database updates required

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the images have the old url-s saved in the database. So you have to change all the old url-s to reflect the new url. You can/should use a plugin for this: try [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/)